# Merge two queries that use different timeframes for min/max/avg

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary` and I have the following table:

```
| id    | date                | ticker | close     |
|-------|---------------------|--------|-----------|
| 39869 | 2019-09-18 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 221.96160 |
| 39870 | 2019-09-17 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 220.70000 |
| 39871 | 2019-09-16 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 219.90000 |
| 39872 | 2019-09-13 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 218.75000 |
| 39873 | 2019-09-12 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 223.09000 |
| 39874 | 2019-09-11 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 223.59000 |
| 39875 | 2019-09-10 00:00:00 | AAPL   | 216.70000 |
```

I have two queries where I am calculating metrics for `52-weeks` and the second query calculates aggregation metrics for `20-days`:

**52-weeks**:

```
SELECT
    Y.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(CLOSE) AS week_52_High,
        DATE AS week_52_High_date,
        MIN(CLOSE) AS week_52_Low,
        DATE AS week_52_Low_date,
        AVG(CLOSE) AS week_52_Avg
    FROM
        `prices`
    WHERE
        DATE >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 52 WEEK AND ticker = "AAPL") Y
    LEFT JOIN prices tmax52 ON
        tmax52.date = Y.week_52_High_date AND tmax52.close = week_52_High
    LEFT JOIN prices tmin52 ON
        tmin52.date = Y.week_52_Low_date AND tmin52.close = week_52_Low
    LEFT JOIN prices tavg52 ON
        tavg52.close = week_52_Avg
```

**20-days**

```
SELECT
    Y.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(CLOSE) AS day_20_High,
        DATE AS day_20_High_date,
        MIN(CLOSE) AS day_20_Low,
        DATE AS day_20_Low_date,
        AVG(CLOSE) AS day_20_Avg
    FROM
        `prices`
    WHERE
        DATE >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 20 DAY AND ticker = "AAPL") Y
    LEFT JOIN prices tmax20 ON
        tmax20.date = Y.day_20_High_date AND tmax20.close = day_20_High
    LEFT JOIN prices tmin20 ON
        tmin20.date = Y.day_20_Low_date AND tmin20.close = day_20_Low
    LEFT JOIN prices tavg20 ON
        tavg20.close = day_20_Avg
```

Both queries calculate the min/max/avg for each close price and attach the days, when this happened.

Any suggestions how to merge these two queries to get everything in 1 output?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: How about UNION ?

Comment: @Strawberry Thx! Using union I get the results below each other. I would like to connect these two column sets together.

Comment: You can do some procedure to call inside both query’s and return the values.

Comment: @Cauca Thx for your reply! I kindly ask you to provide an example as answer.

Comment: you can union both selects and then order teh result, maybe this can solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that your query won't actually work. The correct way to get the dates for the `high` and `low` values is as below. Note that it is meaningless to try and get a date for the average close as it's highly unlikely that the stock will have closed at that price.

```
SELECT
    Y.day_20_High,
    tmax20.DATE AS day_20_High_date,
    Y.day_20_Low,
    tmin20.DATE AS day_20_Low_date,
    Y.day_20_Avg
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(CLOSE) AS day_20_High,
        MIN(CLOSE) AS day_20_Low,
        ROUND(AVG(CLOSE),2) AS day_20_Avg
    FROM
        `prices`
    WHERE
        DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY AND ticker = "AAPL") Y
    LEFT JOIN prices tmax20 ON tmax20.close = Y.day_20_High
    LEFT JOIN prices tmin20 ON tmin20.close = Y.day_20_Low
```

Output (for my sample data)

```
day_20_High     day_20_High_date    day_20_Low  day_20_Low_date     day_20_Avg
107.50          2019-09-20          101.10      2019-09-10          104.05
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4a7c7ca9aa0d0cf2f07d3e52c9a79a54)

Having corrected the query, you can now just `JOIN` to the same query for 52-week data:

```
SELECT
    Y20.day_20_High,
    tmax20.DATE AS day_20_High_date,
    Y20.day_20_Low,
    tmin20.DATE AS day_20_Low_date,
    Y20.day_20_Avg,
    Y52.week_52_High,
    tmax52.DATE AS week_52_High_date,
    Y52.week_52_Low,
    tmin52.DATE AS week_52_Low_date,
    Y52.week_52_Avg
FROM ((
    SELECT
        MAX(CLOSE) AS day_20_High,
        MIN(CLOSE) AS day_20_Low,
        ROUND(AVG(CLOSE),2) AS day_20_Avg
    FROM
        `prices`
    WHERE
        DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY AND ticker = "AAPL") Y20
    LEFT JOIN prices tmax20 ON tmax20.close = Y20.day_20_High
    LEFT JOIN prices tmin20 ON tmin20.close = Y20.day_20_Low)
JOIN ((
    SELECT
        MAX(CLOSE) AS week_52_High,
        MIN(CLOSE) AS week_52_Low,
        ROUND(AVG(CLOSE),2) AS week_52_Avg
    FROM
        `prices`
    WHERE
        DATE >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 52 WEEK AND ticker = "AAPL") Y52
    LEFT JOIN prices tmax52 ON tmax52.close = Y52.week_52_High
    LEFT JOIN prices tmin52 ON tmin52.close = Y52.week_52_Low)
```

Output (for my sample data)

```
day_20_High     day_20_High_date    day_20_Low  day_20_Low_date     day_20_Avg  week_52_High    week_52_High_date   week_52_Low     week_52_Low_date    week_52_Avg
107.50          2019-09-20          101.10      2019-09-10          104.05      109.70          2019-08-24          100.00          2019-08-21          104.19
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4737d708d305538698816038d9189f3d)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to merge your queries one after another:

> ```
> with t as (
>  select 0 as id, 1 as v0, 2 as v1
>  union all select 1 as id, 1 as v0, 2 as v1
> )
>
> select *
> from (
>  select t.*, 'weekly_report' as typ from t
> union all
>  select t.*, 'monthly_report' as typ from t
> ) as t1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | v0 | v1 | typ           
> -: | -: | -: | :-------------
>  0 |  1 |  2 | weekly_report 
>  1 |  1 |  2 | weekly_report 
>  0 |  1 |  2 | monthly_report
>  1 |  1 |  2 | monthly_report
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd691f7e5b49250be4eb3dde20ebae33)*

And to have your results column by column, do a join:

> ```
> with t as (
>  select 0 as id, 1 as v0, 2 as v1
>  union all select 1 as id, 1 as v0, 2 as v1
> )
>
> select t0.id, t0.v0, t0.v1, t1.v0, t1.v1
> from (
>  select * from t
> ) as t0
> full join (
>  select * from t
> ) as t1 on t0.id = t1.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | v0 | v1 | v0 | v1
> -: | -: | -: | -: | -:
>  0 |  1 |  2 |  1 |  2
>  1 |  1 |  2 |  1 |  2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=61198e354694b1da387bd19c23a09f1d)*

Comment: he is using mariadb and neither sql server 2017 nor postgre

Comment: @nbk does that matter? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd691f7e5b49250be4eb3dde20ebae33